# How to add external jar or zip file in the Blackberry project

Tags: blackberry, java-me, jde

I want to add a jar file to my BlackBerry project. I have tried adding the jar file by the following manner ->

- Right click on project  -> properties -> Build -> Imported jar files -> Add

But after that, whenever I try to run the application I get "Module abc.jar not found error".

How do I add a jar file to a BlackBerry project?

Answer (score 1):

**Right click on project->BuildPath->Libraries->Addexternaljar** and then press **ok** it will solved your problem it is for if you are using eclipseplugins.you can see the details [here](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/12002/Add_jar_dependency_923677_11.jsp)

Answer (score 1):

I find out how to do it on JDE environment:

In order to compile with the external JAR, must do right click on project, properties -> Build -> Imported JAR files, and add desired external JARs.

And for adding module to BB simulator for debugging, the way is creating a new project on the same workspace, add the external JAR to it as a resource file, and set the project Build to Library (on properties -> Application -> Project Type).

I hope this could serve.

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work, you might also want to click on the "Order and Export" tab (next to the "Library" tab), and ensure that the checkbox next to your .jar is checked

Comment: I think all u suggest is about eclipse, but I am using blackberry JDE, so please guide me in that way-